# How to make field be BLOB not TINYBLOB?

Tags: java, image, hibernate, orm, blob

How to make field to be BLOB not TINYBLOB?

My mapping is follows:

```
private byte[] ImageBytes;

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(ImageBytes);
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG" /* for instance */, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    ImageBytes = out.toByteArray();
}
```

it causes Hibernate to create TINYBLOB field in MySQL which does not fit an image.

How to make it use BLOB?

The following answer

```
@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB)
```

does not work since `@Lob` annotation has no parameters in my library.

Also I don't want to use ORM-specific or DBMS-specific annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this;

```
@Lob
@Column(name="IMAGE", nullable=false, columnDefinition="blob")
private byte[] imageBytes;
```

And make sure your image data type is `BLOB`.